# How does the IP range work to find a specific computer on a network with separate network addreses?

Tags: networking, range

*This is a question from a homework assignment that I’m confused on. I’m stuck but I think the answer is “manufacturing” (`192.168.1.64`).*

You are the network administrator for an industrial machinery manufacturer in Florida. The company manufacturing facility has four buildings—administration, manufacturing, development, and dispatch.

Each building is assigned a separate network address from the private Class C address of `192.168.1.0`, by virtue of the fact that a subnet mask of `255.255.255.224` is being used. The “administration” building is assigned the subnet ID `192.168.1.32`, “manufacturing” is assigned `192.168.1.64`, “development” is assigned `192.168.1.128`, and “dispatch” is assigned `192.168.1.192`.

A user calls to report a problem accessing one of the company’s four FTP servers. You ask the user for their IP. They report it as `192.168.1.77`. What department is the system that the user is using in?

Comment: +1 for stating you tried and giving the answer you found for a homework question.

Comment: Strange you're being taught class-based addressing, which hasn't been used for decades.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit indeed - "Class C" is an utterly obsolete term in modern networking.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I do not find it strange at all. When curricula were developed for computer networking, they were up to date. What then happens is that such things are taught by inertia. It's probably the same reason why I had to learn token ring networks or IPX.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Okay, `s/strange/disappointing/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mask the address with the subnet mask you get the subnet:

```
192.168.1.77    = 11000000.10101000.00000001.01001101
255.255.255.224 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.11100000
                  ===================================
Subnet          = 11000000.10101000.00000001.01000000
```

Convert it back to decimal, and you have your subnet which you can relate to the department.

Comment: Don't forget that it's not necessary that every network be the same size.  It's perfectly feasible in the OP's example that it's split .0/27 (unused), .32/27 (admin), .64/26 (manufacturing), .128/26 (dev) and .192/26 (dispatch)

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I have been doing this work for years and subnet mask math still confuses me. So no worries. But you can solve this by some simple deductive reasoning from clearly/rationally looking at the following basics given in the question:

- “administration” is assigned `192.168.1.32`.
- “manufacturing” is assigned `192.168.1.64`.
- “development” is assigned `192.168.1.128`.
- “dispatch” is assigned `192.168.1.192`.

Without knowing any subnet mask math, just seeing `192.168.1.32` and `192.168.1.64` shows each network has 32 addresses available in some way. Then knowing that it then wouldn’t be too hard to deduce the following ranges assuming each range has 31 addresses (32 minus 1 for the router/switch address itself) including a broadcast address:

- “administration” (`192.168.1.32`) goes from `192.168.1.33` to `192.168.1.63`.
- “manufacturing” (`192.168.1.64`) goes from `192.168.1.65` to `192.168.1.95`.
- “development” (`192.168.1.128`) goes from `192.168.1.129` to `192.168.1.159`.
- “dispatch” (`192.168.1.192`) goes from `192.168.1.193` to `192.168.1.223`.

Note that since all of the subnets indicate a beginning (aka: router/switch) address plus that 31 address range, `192.168.1.77` therefore fits neatly into the “manufacturing” as you correctly assume.

The “trick” part of this question is the fact that the `192.168.1.96` and `192.168.1.160` subnets are missing. So it seems a bit off if you are unsure how network ranges work. But honestly a setup like this would easily equate to a real world scenario where subnets would not be allocated unless a need arose.